# What permissions are required for Orchard CMS?

Tags: permissions, installation, orchardcms

I used the web platform installer to install the Orchard CMS but when the setup web page comes up for the CMS, once I submit my details, the following error is shown on the orchard system for the first time:

> Setup failed: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation. Access is
>   denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I have checked my application pool and that user has full permissions to the app data folder which is where the local database is created (I think that is where it is falling over).

It creates a error log file at the same time but it is empty which is handy.

Anyone else had any issues with running the first time setup?

I have looked on there project site but troubleshooting documentation is very thin: http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Installing-Orchard.ashx

Comment: I have installed Orchard on several different computers including local test boxes as well as shared servers without problems. Of course others have had problems so you are not alone. Perhaps if you could describe your environment (Version of Windows, 32 or 64 bit etc) it might be helpful.

Comment: Windows server datacenter 64 bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here is a solution.
Although I managed to install Orchard using the existing SQL Server, I was still curious about this issue and not working with SQL Server Compact. Apparently it was some permission problem with folder where SQL CE should be put, well that was my thinking.
Then I found this answer here at SO [Deploying SQL CE 4 to IIS 7 - Special Permissions Needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433541/deploying-sql-ce-4-to-iis-7-special-permissions-needed) and kaboom! that's it. There were no permissions on bin folder for IUSR, even though I added it for parent folder. Hm, whatever happened, now it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

Might be unrealted but the very first thing you should check is whether the app pool is configured to use .NET 4.0.

Comment: I managed to start installation with an existing SQL Server database, although this message remains when I try with built-in data storage (SQL SERVER Compact) It must be an issue with administration, so I will contact hosting provider.