# Trouble Deploying Sql Server CE 4.0 to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-ce

I'm having trouble deploying an ASP.Net application using Sql Server CE 4.0.  I get the following error:

> Access to the database file is not allowed.

I've verified that I'm using the local "add_data" folder in my connection string:

```
<add name="DemoStudy" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.StudyContext.csdl|res://*/Data.StudyContext.ssdl|res://*/Data.StudyContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CRS20SandboxCE.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

I've also tried granting IUSR account full access to the app_data directory, but that didn't seem to help.  [Another SO thread suggests granting IUSR access to the bin directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433541/deploying-sql-ce-4-to-iis-7-special-permissions-needed), but that didn't help either.

**UPDATE:**
Well, it's definitely a permissions issue.  If I give the "Everyone" user group access to the app_data folder, everything works fine.

**QUESTION:**
What is the correct user to give full access to in IIS 7?  It's obviously not IUSR...

Comment: I had the same issue.  App was running as Network Service and kept getting the error from above.  Opening the folder security permissions up wide to Everyone fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One must grant read/write access to the appropriate app_pool user.  In this case,

```
IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
```

Note that the user group must be specified as shown.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure but it think it may be the Network Service account that needs permissions.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried IUSR and Network Service.  But I'll try it again.  Amazing what a dearth of information there is re: deploying sql ce to an asp.net project.  It's a very desirable thing to do.  In any case, it's a dev server and I'm heading out on vacation...this question may languish a bit 'til I get back...I'm a little underwater...

Comment: Change the app pool to run as a dedicated user account which has read/write permissions to the AppData folder.  This is working fine for me on IIS 7+

Comment: @schefdev See my answer below.  You don't need to change the app pool user.  You can grant permission to the appropriate IIS apppool user.